# How can I make a command that makes all my wolves sit and stand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've started a new Minecraft world and decided that I wanted to reach functional invulnerability by having like 50 unnamed wolves follow me around. However, this comes with a few issues, because having them follow around all the time makes it impossible to loot desert temples, they die by the dozen whenever I jump into a ravine, etc. It is a hassle to make them all sit and stand up, so I tried making a command that makes them all sit.

Here's what I tried so far:

Now the key to this seems to be the /data command. The command:

```
/data merge entity @e[name=JackLondon,limit=1] {Sitting:1}
```

allows me to make JackLondon the wolf sit, which is great.

The issue is that the /data command does not readily work with more than one entity at a time and I haven't found a way to circumvent that. I also haven't found a way to make it affect multiple unnamed entities.

Any code that allows me to make wolves or pets in general sit and stand all at once would be welcome.

Comment: "functional invulnerability by having like 50 unnamed wolves follow me around"  Lava, fire, wither roses, berry bushes, dragon, wither, TNT, falling, void, starving, …

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after a short while XD. They are very fun to let loose during illager raids though ^^

Answer (score 10):

You can use /execute to make every wolf execute the /data command and modify its own NBT data:

```
/execute as @e[type=wolf] run data merge entity @s {Sitting:1b}
```

Comment: Excellent! I have a few questions on that solution, though. 1. I'm assuming this will only work on all loaded wolves, correct? 2. If so, setting the NBT tag {Sitting:0b} if I'm away from home wouldn't make any unnamed tamed wolves at home stand? What about named ones? 3. I tried adding more arguments to the @e (namely, distance=100 and Owner=<playerName>) and it stopped working. Why is that? 4. Equally, how would I go about making this in a custom trigger command with command blocks? My attempts have led to the wolves permanently sitting, or it not working. Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: 1: Correct. 2: It shouldn't unless your home is in loaded chunks. Same for named ones. 3: distance=100 means exacly 100 blocks (which is too precise). Use distance=..100 (which means 100 blocks or less). Also, the Owner tag needs a UUID and not a player name. 4: I suggest you create another post for this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: 3. `Owner` is NBT, so you want `nbt={Owner:…}` with the UUID instead of `…`. 4. `/trigger` is explained here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/trigger It also links to the scoreboard page with the details on creating and enabling the trigger scoreboard and how to check it.

Comment: Side note: If you settled near spawn, then the loaded chunks are not an issue - the chunks around world spawn are permaloaded by default. You can also add chunks to the permaloaded chunks using the `/forceload` command. Re 4., I'd rather recommend using a datapack function - doesn't rely on any command blocks being loaded.